# Magento 2 PHP Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[08004] [1040] Too many connections

Tags: magento2, database

When I run a script for **upload products more than 5000**. after 152 products upload showing 
below error. How can I upload thousand of products from csv without error?

> Error: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[08004] [1040]
>   Too many connections in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento23\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php:128
>   Stack trace:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento23\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(128):
>   PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', 'password', Array)
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento23\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(111):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento23\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(406):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento23\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(460):
>   Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_connect()
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento23\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(238):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `store_w...', Array)
>    C:\xampp\htdocs\magento23\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php
>   in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento23\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php
>   on line 144

Comment: Are you using a shared hosting?

Comment: It's run my localhost with cli command.

Comment: Which Magento2 version you are using?

Comment: I am using Magento 2.3

Answer (score 0):

Go to your **mysql configuration file(/etc/my.cnf)** and increase **max_connections** value like

```
e.x : max_connections = 500
```

Comment: Yes, it's added max_connections = 500. but no yet resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24225164/sqlstatehy000-1040-too-many-connections

There are some solution given so it might help you.